# onClick conditional rendering for three conditions

Tags: reactjs

I have `onClick` that I want to hit a certain function depending on the following logic:

```
onClick={
approve && this.handleApproveClick,
!approve && !releaseHold && this.handleDeclineClick,
releaseHold && this.handleReleaseHoldClick
}
```

Oddly enough the last `this.handleReleaseHoldClick` works, while the others do not. What is the correct way to do this? Or do I really need to create a separate button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does only the last work**?

It's a basic `comma operator` case, where the "comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand".

**What is the correct way to do this**?

Since it's a triple-condition function, I'd suggest you to create a class method and simply secure each of possible cases.

```
handleSomeClick = () => {
    if (approve) {
        this.handleApproveClick();
    } else if (!approve && !releaseHold) {
        this.handleDeclineClick();
    } else if (releaseHold) {
        this.handleReleaseHoldClick();
    }
}
```

and inside JSX:

```
onClick={this.handleSomeClick}
```

Comment: You are without a doubt, the kindest user i've ever seen.